# Centering and wrapping with Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am building a GUI in Kivy where the window will need to be horizontally resized. I have three buttons, two small ones either side of a much larger one, which I would like to change position when the window becomes too narrow.

Example image

[image]

The buttons need to be centrally aligned. I can do this by using padding on either side, but when the window becomes too small, the padding also moves to a new line which stops the buttons being aligned centrally. I've also tried experimenting with stack layouts but haven't managed to get anything working with the right alignment.

Is there a straightforward fix for this?

Minimal working example:

```
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window


class Home(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Home, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        BUTTON_WIDTH = 0.1
        BUTTON_HEIGHT = 0.1

        layout = StackLayout(orientation='lr-tb',
                             size=(Window.width, Window.height),
                             pos=self.pos
                             )

        self.add_widget(layout)

        button1 = Button(text='1',
                         size_hint=(BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT)
                         )
        big_button = Button(text='big button',
                            size_hint=(3*BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT)
                            )
        button2 = Button(text='2',
                         size_hint=(BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT)
                         )

        layout.add_widget(button1)
        layout.add_widget(big_button)
        layout.add_widget(button2)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Home()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for making big changes in your app, but I think doing things like extending a `Layout` rather than adding a `Layout` to a `Widget` class makes for simpler code. I also use `kv` to setup the members of the `Home` class. I set the width of the big button to the width of its texture (the text), to keep the text inside the button.

Anyway, here is my version of your code that I think does what you want. I use the `on_size` method (that is called when the size is changed) to do the re-arranging of the buttons:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_string('''
#:set BUTTON_WIDTH 0.1
#:set BUTTON_HEIGHT 0.1
<Home>:
    Button:
        id: b1
        text: '1'
        size_hint: (BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT)
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'center_y': 0.5}
    Button:
        id: big
        text: 'big button'
        size_hint: (None, BUTTON_HEIGHT)
        size_x: self.texture_size[0]
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    Button:
        id: b2
        text: '2'
        size_hint: (BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT)
        pos_hint: {'right':1.0, 'center_y': 0.5}
''')


class Home(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Home, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos_switched = False  # keeps track of whether things have been re-arranged

    def on_size(self, instance, new_size):
        if not self.pos_switched and instance.width <= self.ids.b1.width + self.ids.big.width + self.ids.b2.width:
            # not enough room for the buttons side-by-side, re-arrange
            self.ids.b1.pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5}
            self.ids.b1.y = self.ids.big.y + self.ids.big.height
            self.ids.b2.pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5}
            self.ids.b2.y = self.ids.big.y - self.ids.b2.height
            self.pos_switched = True
        elif self.pos_switched and instance.width > self.ids.b1.width + self.ids.big.width + self.ids.b2.width:
            # ok to move the buttons back to original positions
            self.ids.b1.pos_hint = {'x':0, 'center_y': 0.5}
            self.ids.b2.pos_hint = {'right':1.0, 'center_y': 0.5}
            self.pos_switched = False



class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Home()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can I ask why you prefer the `kv` approach, rather than using Python?

Comment: Just that it separates the display from the logic. I think it makes it easier to understand the logic that way.